# How to set view size to match device screen in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiview, landscape, portrait

I have a UIView that I need to resize to half the height of the screen, it works fine in Portrait mode but if I lunch the app with the iPad in landscape the UIView always get the screen portrait size, any ideas how to get the size at launch and after change in orientation?

I try the following but always get protrait where width = 768 and height = 1024

```
NSLog( @"bounds: %@", NSStringFromCGRect( [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds ) );
NSLog( @"frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect( [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set property `autoresizingMask` of your view to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`.

Or try to place with its value. After setting this value your view will automatically resize after device rotation.